# Downloading historical Tweets via rtweet from Premium API via R

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis, rtweet

I need to extract the Tweets with "#bitcoin" from 2013-04-28 until today from Twitter to do a sentiment analysis.

For this I have access to Twitter's Premium API.

I am using the rtweet package which offers the function search_fullarchive.

My questions:
1. How can I ensure to download e.g. 50,000 Tweets from every day in the intervall from 2013-04-28 until today?

2. Do I have to consider a retryonratelimit=T argument as in "search_tweets"?
3. Which token has to be inserted in the "token"-argument
4. Can I create a dataframe "df_tweets" and the function binds every new downloaded Tweets in it?

Would this function download 50,000 Tweets from every day between 2013-04-28 until 2019-06-02 (note: I have to look up the environment name, df_tweets should be an empty data.frame):

```
bitcointweets <-search_fullarchive(q = "bitcoin", 
n = 50000, 
fromDate = "20130428",
toDate = "20190602",
env_name = "XXX",
parse = T, 
token ="????", 
safedir = df_tweets)
```

Is there an estimate possible how long this download will take?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

First **(point 3)** of all the token argument seems to require a bearer token:

*A token associated with a user-created APP (requires a developer account), which is converted to a bearer token in order to make premium API requests*

which, as you can read up here: [https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/bearer-tokens](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/quick-start/premium-30-day), is generated via a curl request:

```
curl -u 'API key:API secret key' \
  --data 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
  'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
```

with 'API key' and 'API secret key' replaced by your keys.

---

Second **(point 2)**, a premium account allows for *pagination* of tweets, i.e. it provides a token, if the number of tweets to return is higher than the number your account allows per request, e.g. 100. This can be read up in the api reference for premium search: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search
As this feature is not mentioned in the *rtweet* reference, I am not sure that it is implemented at this stage. In order to use this *pagination* you have to provide the arguemnt *next* with the provided token. The twitter reference states:

*This parameter is used to get the next 'page' of results. The value used with the parameter is pulled directly from the response provided by the API, and should not be modified.*

So you might be able to paste your initial query with the pagination argument, if you can retrieve this *next token* via *rtweet*, e.g.

```
# initial example query looking for the term rtweet, filtering for tweets associated with news, excluding retweets and replies, starting on July 1, 2006 and ending on July 2, 2019
query <- "rtweet filter:news -filter:retweets -filter:replies since:2006-07-01 until:2019-07-02"

# next_token retrieved by request
next <- paste0("next:", next_token)

# search
search_fullarchive(query, n = 100, env_name = "your_developer_environment", token = "your_bearer_token")

# something happens and hopefully you get pagination token
.
.
.

# paste token with initial query
query <- paste0(query, " ", "pagination_token")

# search again, but now with pagination token in query
search_fullarchive(query, n = 100, env_name = "your_developer_environment", token = "your_bearer_token")
```

Obviously this query has to be looped until no *pagination token* is returned.

As I do not have experience with the *search_fullarchive()* function at this stage, and I am really not sure if the possibility to receive the *pagiation token* is implemented, I would suggest using curl for searching the full twitter archive.

---

Regarding **(point 4)**, I would suggest using *rbind()* in a loop using the parsed dataframe of tweets (using arugment *parse = TRUE* inside the *search_fullarchive()* function of package *rtweet*).

---

And to your initial question **(point 1)**: Just loop the whole thing until you reach your 50,000 tweets. I don't think that there is any possibility except looping.

Answer (score 0):

Any progress on this? I'm trying something similar but when using the `bearer_token` that was generated in the `token=` argument is resulting in a *"Not a valid access token"* error message.